# Script to move programs to predefined window/desktop configurations

Tags: automator, window-manager, fullscreen

I want to have a specific window/desktop configuration to remain (or switch to).

In detail, I want certain programs to be fullscreen at all times and some in fullsplitscreen (which are respectively on seperate desktops). For example (suppose a single screen), I want (from right to left) Desktop 3 to have my calendar in fullscreen, Desktop 2 to have todoist and mail in splitscreen and desktop 1 to have the remaining screen.

Would anyone have a suggestion where I could start with scripting something like this? I suppose this could be a script that takes the specific windows and arranges them as described above and leave the rest as is. Nothing fancy.

Why I want to automate this arranging of windows:
Currently, when I arrange the programs manually as described above, it sometimes automatically unfullscreens the programs when I plug in a screen (or unplug it).

(For context, I am not familiar at all with how things happen in macOS, I have so experience with scripting in Ubuntu, no idea if that helps here, my laptop is running 13.4).

Comment: I’ve recommended the app [Stay](https://sites.fastspring.com/cordlessdog/product/stay) before, but it isn’t free.  It is rather inexpensive at ~$15

Comment: Hi, Stay seems to be exactly what I want, but I would not call 15 dollars inexpensive... Thank you though!